# how to image load and save it by C

Tags: c, bitmap, image-loading

Firstly, i'm not good at English. So please understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define xsize 570   // x사이즈
#define ysize 456   // y사이즈
#define INPUTFILENAME "robot2.bmp"
#define OUTPUTFILENAME "testout.bmp"

int is_success_open_file(FILE *filename);
int is_BMP(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf);
void store_img(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf, BITMAPINFOHEADER hInfo, RGBQUAD hRGB[], unsigned int InputImg[xsize][ysize], unsigned int OutputImg[xsize][ysize]);
void make_img(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf, BITMAPINFOHEADER hInfo, RGBQUAD hRGB[], unsigned int OutputImg[xsize][ysize]);

int main(void)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER hf;      // "파일정보헤드" 구조체 변수 선언
    BITMAPINFOHEADER hInfo;   // "영상정보헤드" 구조체 변수 선언
    RGBQUAD hRGB[256];        // 팔레트 정보를 위한 배열 선언
    FILE *fp;                 // 파일 포인터

    unsigned int InputImg[xsize][ysize];
    unsigned int OutputImg[xsize][ysize]; // 출력 이미지

    fp = fopen(INPUTFILENAME, "rb");
    if (is_success_open_file(fp) == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /* store_img와 make_img 함수에서 이미 fread 함수를 호출 하지만, main 함수에서도 해야 함. 이유는 잘 모르겠지만 main 함수에서 호출하지 않으면
반환된 이미지 파일을 읽을 수 없게 됨
    fread(&hf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp);
    fread(&hInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, fp);
    fread(hRGB, sizeof(RGBQUAD), 256, fp);*/

    // store_img 함수 호출
    store_img(hf, hInfo, hRGB, InputImg, OutputImg);


    printf("size of BITMAPINFOHEADER = %d\n", hInfo.biSize);     // BITMAPINFOHEADER 구조체의 크기
    printf("WIDTH OF IMG = %d\n", hInfo.biWidth);       // 이미지의 가로 크기
    printf("HEIGHT OF IMG = %d\n", hInfo.biHeight);     // 이미지의 세로 크기
    printf("BYTE SIZE OF IMG = %d\n", hf.bfSize);               // byte 단위로 파일 전체 크기
    printf("IS IMG BMP? = %hx.  if result : 4d42, it means BMP\n", hf.bfType);                // "파일이 BMP"가 맞는지
    printf("NUMBER OF USED COLORS = %d\n", hInfo.biClrUsed);   // 실제 사용 색상 수
    printf("BIT PER PIXEL = %d\n", hInfo.biBitCount); // 픽셀당 비트 수 (컬러, 흑백 구별)

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

int is_success_open_file(FILE *filename)
{
    if (filename == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to open file\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("successed to open file\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int is_BMP(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf)
{
    if (hf.bfType != 0x4D42) // 비트맵 파일이 맞는지 판단
    {
        printf("file is not BMP\n\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file is BMP.\n\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void store_img(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf, BITMAPINFOHEADER hInfo, RGBQUAD hRGB[], unsigned int InputImg[xsize][ysize], unsigned int OutputImg[xsize][ysize])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(INPUTFILENAME, "rb");

    fread(&hf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp);
    fread(&hInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, fp);
    fread(hRGB, sizeof(RGBQUAD), 256, fp);
    fread(InputImg, xsize * ysize, 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    for(int i = 0; i < xsize; i++)
    {
        for(int k =0; k < ysize; k++)
        {
            OutputImg[i][k] = InputImg[i][k];
        }
    }
    make_img(hf, hInfo, hRGB, OutputImg);

}

void make_img(BITMAPFILEHEADER hf, BITMAPINFOHEADER hInfo, RGBQUAD hRGB[], unsigned int OutputImg[xsize][ysize])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(OUTPUTFILENAME, "wb");

    fwrite(&hf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&hInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, fp);
    fwrite(hRGB, sizeof(RGBQUAD), 256, fp);
    fwrite(OutputImg, xsize * ysize, 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

I try to load image and save it.
when I run this, there is no compile Error. But Nothing's printed and the file's shut down in five seconds.
What I need to do? please answer.. I need your help....

print, and save image file

Comment: Most likely fopen failed.  Is robot2.bmp in the current directory of the process?

Comment: A few remarks: The image buffers are `[xsize][ysize]` but should be `[ysize][xsize]`. The `fread` and `fwrite` size is `xsize * ysize` which should be `xsize * ysize * sizeof(unsigned int)`. And `store_img()` opens the input file, which you already opened. And `make_img()` opens the output file but does not check its success. Not sure how these would affect "the file's shut down in five seconds" though. Which "file is shut down"? Note that the file you created *doesn't have enough pixel data*.